# Win7 official iso download

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

does anybody have an idea where to get the official win7 iso?
All the download links that i found on the web seems to be invalid.
(iam not talking about pirated versions from dubious sources. just the iso's of the original installation medias that microsoft provides totally legally)

e.g.: 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/where-can-i-download-windows-7-iso-i-have-a/7d964b05-2be9-4800-bc7f-3ca30356fc3d
http://www.w7forums.com/threads/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-image-downloads.12325/ http://techverse.net/download-windows-7-iso-x86-x64-microsofts-official-servers/

(looking for german versions)

does anybody have some newer informations?

thanks.

Comment: @techie007 the links are dead - 
at least the sp1 versions seems do be down

Comment: Just the SP1 links seem dead, the SP0 links all seem to work fine still.  Regardless, it's the same question, even if it needs some updating.

Comment: @techie007 but it seems not to be recommendend to use the old isos.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch - Those are the only official links we have.  So take what you can get.

Comment: The "old ISOs" should work as good as they were when they were new. ;)

Comment: separate installing the patches or SP results in bigger installations sizes that may be relevant if SSDs are used. (beside the fact that it is timeconsuming)

Comment: @vlad_tepesch - You can combine the SP0 ISO image and the SP1 patches and create an SP1 image (disc/ISO). The process is called "slipstreaming". Look here: [sevenforums-slipstream-windows-7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/145343-slipstream-windows-7-sp1-into-installation-dvd-iso-file.html) or Google ***"slipstream windows 7"***, for more info.

Comment: @techie007 seems that the download links have been fixed. any way to restore old revision of the post in the other thread or just reedit it?